# bluetooth did not work

Tags: 14.04

The result is as follows when I Run `lsmod` command in terminal:

```
spnaik@spnaik-Vostro-2520:~$  lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ppp_deflate            12806  0 
bsd_comp               12785  0 
ppp_async              17205  1 
crc_ccitt              12627  1 ppp_async
nls_utf8               12493  1 
isofs                  39203  1 
option                 33967  2 
huawei_cdc_ncm         12846  0 
cdc_wdm                18509  1 huawei_cdc_ncm
cdc_ncm                19695  1 huawei_cdc_ncm
usb_wwan               19733  1 option
usbserial              38902  7 option,usb_wwan
usbnet                 37865  2 huawei_cdc_ncm,cdc_ncm
nvram                  14027  0 
rfcomm                 53664  0 
bnep                   18895  2 
bluetooth             342263  10 bnep,rfcomm
uvcvideo               71309  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13048  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13170  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         39258  1 uvcvideo
videodev              108503  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
dell_wmi               12665  0 
sparse_keymap          13708  1 dell_wmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45303  1 
snd_hda_codec_cirrus    14287  1 
snd_hda_intel          42730  3 
snd_hda_codec         164067  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                85501  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
dell_laptop            17808  0 
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
dcdbas                 14448  1 dell_laptop
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            25135  1 snd_seq_midi
i915                  705396  4 
snd_seq                55383  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
drm_kms_helper         46907  1 i915
intel_rapl             18301  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    13845  0 
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
intel_powerclamp       14239  0 
coretemp               13195  0 
snd_timer              28584  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
crc32_pclmul           12967  0 
drm                   243792  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17456  0 
snd                    60871  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_cirrus,snd_seq_midi
wl                   3999690  0 
joydev                 17101  0 
mei_me                 14099  0 
serio_raw              13230  0 
lpc_ich                16864  0 
lib80211               14040  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
mei                    66735  1 mei_me
cfg80211              409394  1 wl
soundcore              12600  1 snd
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
wmi                    18673  1 dell_wmi
parport_pc             31981  0 
ppdev                  17391  0 
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40836  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
video                  18903  1 i915
mac_hid                13037  0 
ums_realtek            17733  0 
usb_storage            48417  2 ums_realtek
hid_generic            12492  0 
usbhid                 46997  0 
hid                    87604  2 hid_generic,usbhid
ahci                   25579  2 
libahci                26754  1 ahci
psmouse                91033  0 
r8169                  61562  0 
mii                    13654  2 r8169,usbnet
spnaik@spnaik-Vostro-2520:~$
```

Comment: Please add info about your Ubuntu version and elaborate on your issue a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Based off the form of your question, it's difficult(for me) to determine direct cause, however, a driver problem would be the simplest, most direct approach. Please update your drivers by following the instructions in this link, then edit your question with further details(OS Version, clear description of issue, etc.).:
http://www.ehow.com/how_5976269_update-drivers-ubuntu.html

if the link above does not help you, check the following link:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth

in particular the section on configuring bluetooth settings.